# Using Postgre and MySQL Side by Side on a Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, postgresql

I'm thinking of checking out Postgre and was curious: Can you run MySQL and Postgre simultaneously on a Mac?

I'm currently using MAMP Pro, which includes PHP and MySQL. It would be cool if I could install Postgre on my laptop, create a Postgre database and duplicate some of my MySQL tables there.

Then I could create a test page with connections to both databases (MySQL and Postgre) and post similar queries targeting Postgre and MySQL side by side.

Would this be easy to do, or are there some technical challenges or dangers I should be aware of?

Comment: It's usually abbreviated "Postgres".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run both Postgres and MySQL on your Mac without conflicts.

There are several ways [install Postgres on a Mac](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/). You can use a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). But the simplest seems to be to [download it as a normal app](http://postgresapp.com/) and it should [work with MAMP just fine](http://postgresapp.com/documentation//configuration-php.html).